# How to use SASS to convert style.scss to style.css

Tags: windows, sass

I have just installed Ruby 1.9.3-p448 as it is recommended by ruby team. I went back to http://sass-lang.com/install and folow the commands:

```
gem install sass
```

and check if i succeed the instalation with:

```
sass -v
```

Everything went nice and sexy, version name was displayed in my cmd. Installation process was now completed so I went to create my first SASS file: style.scss ...

How do I compile my style.scss file in to style.css?

Comment: marked down due to waffle intro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMD you need to be in the correct folder then tell sass to watch your scss file, it will then compile it to css with every save in your editor...

```
sass --watch main.scss:main.css
```

This will watch a file called main.scss and compile it into another file called main.css.
If the main.css file doesn't exist, it will create it, if it does exist it will overwrite it.

Comment: Also if you want to compile numerous css files at once then you can tell sass to watch a folder instead, replace the main.scss with the folder name

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what wushudude said, what I like to do is open up an explorer window and navigate to where my files are, say for instance "C:\projects\myproject\assets" (assuming you have a css/sass folder in there), then hold down Shift and then right click anywhere in the assets folder and there's an option to "Open command prompt here" or something like that. That makes it easier so you don't have to type in the location of your files in the CMD window.

In that case you would do `sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/main.css`

Comment: That is some useful tip. Thank for that.